# Issue with bootstrap sub-menu hovering

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, submenu, jquery-hover

I am currently using a sub-menu implementation in twitter bootstrap. The lines of code are as follows -

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu toggle-drop-down">

 <li style="left: 100px; position: absolute; top: -18px;">
  <img src="@{'/public/images/modal_arrow.png'}">
 </li>

 <li>
  <a href="/editSystemNotification/${notification.id}">Edit</a>
 </li>                                                          

 <li class="dropdown-submenu">
  <a class="sendSettings" href="/editSystemNotification/${notification.id}">Send</a>
 </li>

</ul>
```

Javascript code: -

```
var subList = "<ul class=\"sublist-remove dropdown-menu\"><li><a tabindex='-1' href=\"#\"><i class=\"fa fa-mail-forward\"></i> Send Mail</a></li><li><a href=\"#\"><i class=\"fa fa-hand-o-up\"></i> Notify</a></li></ul>";
    $(".sendSettings").hover(function(e) {
            console.log("hello world");
            $('.sublist-remove').remove();
            e.stopPropagation();
            $(this).parent().append(subList);
        });
```

But when I am trying to hover on the submenu section, I can find the main dropdown element is being hovered on and hence its giving a flickering effect. And I am not able to click on the sub-menu.

Please help with the issue as in where have I gone wrong?

Comment: I found that it is happening because of $('.sublist-remove').remove();
Although this statement is needed but not sure how to handle it in a different way.
Some answers please...

Comment: unsuccessfully tried to reproduce your problem in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MuQdf/2/). maybe missing some css?

Comment: You are missing the bootstrap css. Thats the reason you aren't getting the submenu.

Comment: Help others, by answering your own question and noting any relevant information like any errors you got and what you did to resolve your issue. If the Bootstrap css was not linked then you should have got an error in your browser's console window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you are using Bootstrap 2? Submenus are removed in Bootstrap 3. An example of working submenus in Bootstrap 3 can be found at http://www.bootply.com/86684